# Deduplicate records from existing delta table in memory

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

We have a delta table on production that has a lot of duplicate rows, we could read and do `dropDuplicates()` on the delta table but the problem is the volume of the data is pretty huge we can't read it and remove duplicates and merge the new data as will take a long time. Is there a way to delete duplicate rows from the delta table without reading it to a dataframe like an in memory operation

we tried this sql query it created a new smaller parquet file but after vaccum optimize everything got deleted

```sql
MERGE INTO delta.`{delta_table_path}` AS target
USING (SELECT DISTINCT {', '.join(columns_to_check)} FROM temp_delta_table) AS source
ON target.col = source.col AND target.col1 = source.col1
WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE
```

Answer (score 0):

A Delta Table is "only" parquet files with some metadata. To do anything with it, you must read the table into memory, at least partially.

To drop duplicates, where you have to match each record, you must read the whole table (at least the columns needed to check for duplicates) into memory. There is just no way around it.

You don't have to merge it, though, if removing the duplicates is a one-time operation. You could overwrite the whole table.